# Windows Store 8.1. XAML Progress Bar between pages

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am having a problem with a page in my Windows 8.1 Store App that is taking a long time to render - it is a grid with a number of columns and rows that gets bound to data on loading of the page.
It is not the loading of the data that is slow but the actual binding of the data to the grid.

I ideally want to display a dialog bar to indicate to the user that something is loading and they have clicked on the previous navigate button okay.

I saw someone mention the possibility of having a "loading page" which only has a progress bar in it - and I thought this solution might work but I can't work out in what event of the loading page should I navigate to the actual page.

i.e.
User clicks button which calls

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(LoadingPage));
```

Loading Page displays a progress bar

I know need to be able to call

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ActualPage));
```

The user sees the progress bar whilst ActualPage loads.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Would you consider using a gridview?
Depends on your data model but gridview has built-in UI virtualization tactics to load objects incrementally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the support team at DEVExpress I have a solution to my problem.

Firstly on the page that takes time to load I have wrapped my Grid in a ContentControl

```
<ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Name="Content">
    <!-- Grid in here -->
</ContentControl>
```

I then added a TextBlock which I will use as to display "Loading..." to my page. I have called this control indicator.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="indicator" Text="Loading..." />
```

I have attached the following method to the Loaded event of the page which uses a timer

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    indicator.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
    t.Tick += (dd, ee) =>
    {
        t.Stop();
        Content.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    };
    t.Start();
}
```

Then when the gridcontrol has Loaded I hide the indicator TextBlock

```
void gridControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    indicator.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

This works perfectly for me. I can't use the Windows 8 ProgressBar control because the animation is loaded on the same thread that loads the grid - but I am happy enough to have any indicator.

Also thanks Brian Stump for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

First, I will suggest using a ListView or GridView to display your databound objects because of build-in UI virtualization.

However, maybe this will work for your situation.

Do you know when your page is ready to display? If so, place a progress ring *in front of* your grid while it loads in the background.

```
<Grid x:Name="FullPageGrid">
        <Grid x:Name="YourGridContent">

        </Grid>
        <Grid Background="White" Visibility="Visible" x:Name="ProgressRingGrid">
            <ProgressRing IsActive="True"></ProgressRing>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

When the data is fully loaded, change the visibility of the "ProgressRingGrid" to Visibility="Collapsed"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions- unfortunately it is a 3rd party grid control so I can't avail of the virtualisation options. I have contacted the 3rd party to see if they have any suggestions.

Comment: Also as far as I know I don't think I have any way of knowing that the page has finished loading- it would be perfect if there was some event that could fire as soon as everything is loaded. I would then set the Visibility of the grid to Collapsed initially let the page load and the user see that they have navigated and then change the visibility of the grid after that. I am toying with the idea of even doing this on a timer.

Comment: are you using a data template to set the objects in the grid? Each framework element will have a 'Loaded' event which you can attach an event handler to. If you can find the last element that's going to load then change the visibility in the event handler.

Comment: I've tried attaching event handlers to the Loaded events of all the controls but these all seem to fire before the page is actually displayed. Are you saying that the Loaded event of the last control to load will be fired after the page is displayed?

Comment: The loaded event fires when the content has been rendered. If you are using a custom control from a 3rd party then maybe there's some additional rendering that takes place afterward. What control are you using?

Comment: It's a DEV Express grid. I'll do some experimenting to see if I can figure out why the Loaded events all seem to happen before the page displays when I debug.